# Difference between あく and ひらく

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know the difference between these words, please write some example sentences.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [ひらく / とじる vs. あける / しめる](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6449/542)

Comment: ^That link is helpful but I don't think it answers the question.  Unless I'm missing something it just says that the two are used differently without saying why.

Comment: @user3856370 I rather think the accepted answer in that link tells sufficiently how and why they're different, and becomes a superset of what needs to be answered here.

Comment: @broccoliforest Your right. I guess I was getting confused with how you know when to use あく or あける for example when they can both be transitive and intransitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in Flaw's comment, あく is intransitive and ひらく can be both. The transitive form of あく is 開ける（あける）. And don't confuse 開くwith 空く（あく）which means to become vacant.

Answer (score 3):

> 開く（あく）to be opened
>
> その店は開く
>    This shop is opened
>
> 開く（ひらく）to open
>
> 私は窓を開く I open a window

Comment: It seems your answer tries to distinguish them by transitivity. However, ひらく can be transitive or intransitive while あく is intransitive.